# iOS AWS SDK AWSCognitoIdentityProviderModel.h compile error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-ios

I've been working with Amazon Web Services iOS SDK and came across an interesting compile error due to a line in the SDK.

In AWSCognitoIdentityProviderModel.h the error appears at the line:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * _Nullable mutable;
```

The error states "Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers".

It looks like Xcode does not like using the keyword 'mutable' as a property name and will not compile.

However, this [demo](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/CognitoYourUserPools-Sample/Objective-C) uses the same exact SDK with the same offending line and compiles just fine.

Why is this an error in one project and not an error in the demo project?

Comment: What is the version of SDK that you are using? Whats the target OS version for the app?

Comment: @RohanDubal I am using the latest SDK available on Cocoapods which is 2.4.5. Target OS version for the app is 8.4. I got around this by just renaming that variable but I'm still wondering how it could compile with no modification.